# Using MediaRecorder: getting an error seemingly when I'm setting the source of a live video preview

Tags: javascript, dom, web-mediarecorder

I'm experimenting with MediaRecorder and was able to actually record video, but when I attempt to give a live preview of the video, I just get the following [two error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB4o0.png), which seem to just refer to the same issue:

- `GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/[object%20MediaStream] 404 (NOT FOUND)`
- `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because not supported source was found`

I have checked and seen other similar posts and haven't been able to find a solution that works.
Here's the code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  recordButton = document.getElementById('record');
  stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');

  // get video & audio stream from user
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true
  })
  .then(function (stream) {
    liveStream = stream;

    var liveVideo = document.getElementById('live');
    liveVideo.src = stream;
    liveVideo.play();

    recordButton.disabled = false;
    recordButton.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
    stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);

  });
};
```

I believe that `liveVideo.src = stream;` may be causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but replacing the line `liveVideo.src = stream;` with `liveVideo.srcObject = liveStream;` fixes the issue